# Best practice to send periodic updates to android app?

Tags: android, sockets, server

I am new to android development and I was wondering about experienced devs opinions on how to go about updating information in my app. It is a Google map based app that allows anonymous users from my campus to drop events at certain locations. Upon startup, the app will need to obtain the current list of active user generated events and periodically fetch updates while alive in case other events have been created so it can update its list and play an animation. Thoughts? I know how to rig a working solution for this using sockets and a server, I'm just wondering what the *best* implementation is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to send updates is through GCM push notifications, check [this link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).